# C++ Library loaded successfully via java application but native method call crashes JVM

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, jvm, java-native-interface

I have Created one test Program to check My DLLs Via JNI call on native Side,DLL  is loaded successfully using  Runtime.getRuntime().loadLibrary("CppProj")
as I have printed message on  successful loading.
DLL name is CppProj.dll , path for cpp library configured well in Eclipse configurations, CppProj.dll and CppProj.lib both files are present in that location.

Now on Calling a parameterized native call from java application  on that DLL file Crashes JVM .
Java call is as Follows

```
public class TestNativeInterfaceImpl implements TestNativeInterface
{   
@Override
public native void init(String cppLogConfigFilePath, String cSharpLogConfigFilePath, ErrorWrapper errorWrapper);

}

TestNativeInterface  testNativeInterface = new TestNativeInterfaceImpl(); 

TestNativeInterface.init(CPP_LOG_CONFIG_FILE__PATH,CSHARP_LOG_CONFIG_FILE__PATH,errorWrapper);

TestNativeInterface has its implementation class TestNativeInterfaceImpl.
```

On Cpp Side Receiving method Signature is

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_TestNativeInterfaceImpl_init
    (JNIEnv * env, jobject jObj, jstring jstringCppConfigFilePath, jstring jstringCSharpConfigFilePath, jobject jObjError) 
{

 // operations

}
```

JVM crashes While calling this method,Can anyone suggest what could be wrong in it?

Comment: Please format your code properly. Also, do you have a Stacktrace of the crash? If so, please post the stack trace.

Comment: stack trace is too long to post

Comment: Please provide some more information (e.g. how does your header file created with javah look like?). It could as well crash in `// operations` section. `TestNativeInterface.init(CPP_LOG...` is this how you call the native method? Shouldn't that be `testNativeInterface.init(...` ?!

Comment: yes i am calling through testNativeInterface.init(...